# How to make the animation of the linearlayout look expandble

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I have a button and a linearlayout.The button is clicked and I make the layout visible.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate
            android:duration="700"
            android:fromXDelta="100%"
            android:fromYDelta="0%"
            android:toXDelta="0%"
            android:toYDelta="0%" />
    </set>
```

When clicked again, I add animation in the opposite direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

My processes are running smoothly but linearlayout comes from x 100 of the screen and disappears from x 100.But what I want is that the button does not appear beyond its size.For this, how can I edit it as if it is entering the button with only animation, without creating an expandble layout?
[image]

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/marinasSearchLinear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:background="@drawable/pin_back"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/marinasSearchBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/marinasSearchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="-40dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="@string/search_marinas"
            app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_null" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/marinasSearchBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pin_back"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:tag="@string/defaultspin"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

animation disappearing from a single element instead of full screen is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem.The problem was adding an extra layout as the parent layout where the search view should disappear.In this way, it has become that it will disappear from the size of the layout that surrounds itself, not the main layout.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/marinasSearchFrame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:translationX="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/marinasSearchBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/marinasSearchLinear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@drawable/pin_back"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:outlineProvider="none"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:translationZ="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/marinasSearchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="-40dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:queryHint="@string/search_marinas"
                app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_null" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/marinasSearchBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pin_back"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:tag="@string/defaultspin"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```